# C# Find a path with only a part of a path

Tags: c#

I want to search for a path which contains a specific string.

And i dont know in which path i want to search.

Example:

Search in the whole c:\ drive

String: Setup\State

Should find this path:

C:\Windows\Setup\State

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Directory.EnumerateDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383462(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var paths = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(".. the path you want to search into..", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .Where(path => path.Contains("Setup\State"));
```

Don't forget the namespaces:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Thank you Ahmad Ibrahim. I think it will work but i now get an error: access of path: "C:\Documents and Settings" denied. How can i solve that and allow it?

Comment: @N.Hoyer I don't know, but there're questions about this issue (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963888 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986293)

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
//checks if directory exists. 
if (Directory.Exists(directpryPath))
        {
            //do something is path exists
        }
```

Comment: Er, no. The question is "how do I find a directory where it's name contains a specific string" and not "how do I tell if a directory exists"