# Read folder as admin in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, admin

i'm trying to find a file into "C:\" folder using something like this:

```
var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\", "VBoxManage.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

the code works fine if i'm not trying to read a directory which need admin permission.
I've added in my app.manifest this line:

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

the app ask for admin privilege when runned, but still giving an error like this:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Permission to 'C:\Documents and Settings' denied.'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Writing C# code and/or running as admin does not mean admin account magically gets permissions to places admin does not naturally have permissions too...

Comment: In current Windows, "Documents and Settings" is a Junction to "Users" and can cause issues. What happens if you try to run your program "As Administrator"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963888/c-sharp-access-to-the-path-c-documents-and-settings-is-denied says this problem is related to that folder, which is a junction point as NetMage said.

Comment: On a side note, scanning the whole C drive to look for a particular executable is a bad idea in general. See if `VBoxManage.exe` somehow lists itself in the registry, or under `PATH`.

Comment: `C:\Documents and Settings` is not even accessible to administrators. It's just an alias for `C:\Users`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote these extension methods to handle skipping inaccessible files and folders:

```
#region SafeWalk
public static class SafeWalk {
    [Flags]
    public enum ReturnOptions {
        ReturnFiles = 1, ReturnDirectories = 2, ReturnBoth = 3
    }

    const string AllFiles = "*.*";

#region File and Directory Names
    // File and Directory Name Tree Walkers
#region File and Dir Names
    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(this DirectoryInfo di, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(this DirectoryInfo di, string filePattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(filePattern, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(this DirectoryInfo di, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(filePattern, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(this string path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(this string path, string filePattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(filePattern, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(this string path, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, ReturnOptions returnOpt = ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth) {
        var searchQueue = new Queue<string>() { path };

        while (searchQueue.Count > 0) {
            var cdn = searchQueue.Dequeue();

            IEnumerable<string> cdiFiles = null;
            if (returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles)) {
                try {
                    cdiFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(cdn, filePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                }

                if (cdiFiles != null)
                    foreach (var filename in cdiFiles)
                        yield return filename;
            }

            if ((!returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles) || cdiFiles != null) && (returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories) || searchOpt.HasFlag(SearchOption.AllDirectories))) { // skip if file enumeration failed
                IEnumerable<string> cdiDirs = null;
                try {
                    cdiDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(cdn, dirPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                }

                if (cdiDirs != null) {
                    foreach (var dirname in cdiDirs) {
                        if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            searchQueue.Enqueue(dirname);

                        if (returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories))
                            yield return dirname;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
#endregion
#region File Names
    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileNames(this string path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileNames(this string path, string filePattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(filePattern, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileNames(this string path, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(filePattern, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileNames(this DirectoryInfo path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileNames(this DirectoryInfo path, string filePattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(filePattern, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateFileNames(this DirectoryInfo path, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(filePattern, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles);
#endregion
#region Dir Names
    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateDirectoryNames(this string path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateDirectoryNames(this string path, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateDirectoryNames(this DirectoryInfo path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories);

    public static IEnumerable<string> SafeEnumerateDirectoryNames(this DirectoryInfo path, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        path.FullName.SafeEnumerateFileAndDirNames(AllFiles, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories);
#endregion
#endregion

#region File and Directory Infos
    // File and Directory Info Tree Walkers
#region File System Infos
    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(this string path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, ReturnOptions returnOpt = ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, returnOpt);

    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(this string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, ReturnOptions returnOpt = ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(searchPattern, searchPattern, searchOpt, returnOpt);

    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(this string path, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, ReturnOptions returnOpt = ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(filePattern, dirPattern, searchOpt, returnOpt);

    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, ReturnOptions returnOpt = ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth) =>
        di.SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, returnOpt);

    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, ReturnOptions returnOpt = ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth) =>
        di.SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(searchPattern, searchPattern, searchOpt, returnOpt);

    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly, ReturnOptions returnOpt = ReturnOptions.ReturnBoth) {
        var searchQueue = new Queue<DirectoryInfo>();
        searchQueue.Enqueue(di);
        while (searchQueue.Count > 0) {
            var cdi = searchQueue.Dequeue();

            IEnumerable<string> cdiFiles = null;
            if (returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles)) {
                try {
                    cdiFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(cdi.FullName, filePattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                }

                if (cdiFiles != null) {
                    var cfis = new ConcurrentBag<FileInfo>();
                    cdiFiles.AsParallel()
                            .ForAll(f => {
                                try {
                                    cfis.Add(new FileInfo(f));
                                }
                                catch (Exception) {
                                }
                            });

                    foreach (var fi in cfis)
                        yield return fi;
                }
            }

            if ((!returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles) || cdiFiles != null) && (returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories) || searchOpt.HasFlag(SearchOption.AllDirectories))) { // skip if file enumeration failed
                IEnumerable<string> cdiDirs = null;
                try {
                    cdiDirs = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(cdi.FullName, dirPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                }
                catch (Exception) {
                }

                if (cdiDirs != null) {
                    var cdis = new ConcurrentBag<DirectoryInfo>();
                    cdiDirs.AsParallel()
                           .ForAll(d => {
                               try {
                                   cdis.Add(new DirectoryInfo(d));
                               }
                               catch (Exception) {
                               }
                           });
                    foreach (var rdi in cdis) {
                        if (returnOpt.HasFlag(ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories))
                            yield return rdi;
                        if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                            searchQueue.Enqueue(rdi);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
#endregion
#region File Infos
    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> SafeEnumerateFileInfos(this string path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles).Cast<FileInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> SafeEnumerateFileInfos(this string path, string filePattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(filePattern, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles).Cast<FileInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> SafeEnumerateFileInfos(this string path, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(filePattern, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles).Cast<FileInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> SafeEnumerateFileInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles).Cast<FileInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> SafeEnumerateFileInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, string filePattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(filePattern, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles).Cast<FileInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> SafeEnumerateFileInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, string filePattern, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(filePattern, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnFiles).Cast<FileInfo>();
#endregion
#region Directory Infos
    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> SafeEnumerateDirectoryInfos(this string path, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories).Cast<DirectoryInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> SafeEnumerateDirectoryInfos(this string path, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        new DirectoryInfo(path).SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories).Cast<DirectoryInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> SafeEnumerateDirectoryInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, AllFiles, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories).Cast<DirectoryInfo>();

    public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> SafeEnumerateDirectoryInfos(this DirectoryInfo di, string dirPattern, SearchOption searchOpt = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) =>
        di.SafeEnumerateFileSystemInfos(AllFiles, dirPattern, searchOpt, ReturnOptions.ReturnDirectories).Cast<DirectoryInfo>();
#endregion
#endregion
}
#endregion
```

With these defined you can do:

```
var ans = @"C:\".SafeEnumerateFileNames("VBoxManage.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```