# Access C:\Documents and Settings\ and subfolders like TreeSize application is able to

Tags: c#, directory-structure, uac, access-denied, administrator

I have seen this question multiple times posted yet a clear answer has not been given (except that it should not be possible, yet TreeSize does it..., so does a virusscanner).

I'm creating a C# application that needs to scan a drive on folders/files and see if they are changed (by creating a checksum).

By scanning the C:\Document and Settings\ (or C:\Users\), it is not fully accessible. The thing is: TreeSize (a scanning application to see where your diskspace has been used) is able to scan everything... So how do they do it?

What have I tried without success:

1. Using `app.manifest` to `requireAdministrator` rights when starting the application.
2. Using `Directory.GetFiles(<path>)` and `Directory.GetDirectories(<path>)` to obtain all files / directories.
3. Add a `FileSystemAuditRule` to the `FileSecurity (AccessControl)` which did not give me access.
4. Tried decompiling TreeSize, yet it has been made with Delphi as far I could see... So no success;
5. Read multiple similar Stackoverflow posts, where one said: "You are running as administrator, but is your process elevated?" Which I did not understand. He never explained if there is a difference between Administrator rights and the process being elevated. Is there a difference between those?
   ([C# Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\' is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963888/c-sharp-access-to-the-path-c-documents-and-settings-is-denied))

Comment: Even an administrator account can't access _all_ files.

Comment: shift right click your exe and try run as administrator

Comment: Your application would need read access to be able to compute the checksum. TreeSize would only need access to scan files. I don't know if that influences your solution.

Comment: @PalleDue That may be the case for TreeSize... Yet reading out all the files... I suppose a virusscanner also has permission to do this... So what is different?

Comment: A virus scanner is a different beast, I think it hard to write your own.